# App to find the best time considering team member's schedule

Tags: time-management, scheduling

We are all busy college students in a big team with different schedules and availability. Something that allows each of us to enter when we are available and will find the best match for meetings. Perhaps there's no perfect time but it should find a time where it makes most of the people happy.

Comment: To play devil’s advocate: do you truly imagine that a bunch of students are diligently going to update their status in the app? If so, things have changed greatly (unrecognizably) since my student days  My money says that you will end up doing it as we did, face to face (usually down the pub/student union) whenever you all happen to be together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used any apps myself for this purpose, but here are a list of Android apps that help in personal group time management:

- [TimeTree](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=works.jubilee.timetree&&referrer=utm_campaign%3DWebsite%26utm_medium%3Dad-analytics%26utm_content%3D818af461-32cb-4e6c-a3f6-8dc8a1c5b115%26utm_source%3Dflurry)
- [Looping](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=familynet.de.src)
- [Cozi Family organizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cozi.androidfree)
- [FamCal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appxy.famcalgef)

Most of them focus on time scheduling in a family, but can be easily extended to friend groups.